# Logind.conf HandleLidSwitchDocked

Tags: power-management, lid, systemd-logind

I've been trying to do a clamshell mode setup for my computer and I've seen many suggestions to use `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`.  However this is not really what I want to do since I only want to keep the computer on if it is connected to a monitor.  When it is not connected to a monitor I would like it to `hibernate`.

While looking through the [logind.conf documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html), it describes a parameter called `HandleLidSwitchDocked`.  This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, it does not seem to be supported in Ubuntu (currently running 14.04).

Is there any way to enable this?